# Make title fit in beamer slides footer

Tags: beamer

I'm doing a presentation with a long title, with code like the following

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\title{...}
\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

and it doesn't fit in the middle section of the footnote at the bottom of each slide where titles are included. Is there a way to modify the size of the font within just this part of the footnote or use an abbreviated form of the title without modifying how it appears on my title page?

Comment: You can use the optional argument to give a shorter alternative: `\title[short]{really long title}`.

Comment: I'd go with the abbreviated version @Skillmon explained, but just for completeness: you can change the size with `\setbeamerfont{title in head/foot}{size=\tiny}`